# Ban IP by country via .htaccess but allow certain IPs from that country

Tags: .htaccess, country

.htaccess files so please bear with me. I would just like to know if there is any way I can ban all IP from a specific country but only allow perhaps one or two IPs from the banned country access to the site. Is this possible ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.countryipblocks.net/country-blocks/htaccess-deny-format/

To allow some ips use something like

```
Order deny, allow
Allow from 1.2.3.4
```

**EDIT** to clarify where to put them.

I don't see the use of `<limit>` so I removed that.

```
Order deny, allow
#ips from the blocked countries that are are allowed
Allow from YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY


# 'deny'-code from website 
# only copy the lines starting with 'deny'
deny from XXX.XXX.XX.X/XX 
deny from XXX.XXX.XX.X/XX 
deny from XXX.XXX.XX.X/XX 
# lines starting with a hash are comments so can be removed

# all other ips are allowed
```

Comment: <code><Limit GET POST>


order allow,deny


# Country: XXXXXX


# ISO Code: XX


# Total Networks: XXX


# Total Subnets:  XXXXX


deny from XXX.XXX.XX.X/XX


deny from XXX.XXX.XX.X/XX


deny from XXX.XXX.XX.X/XX


#


allow from all


</Limit> </code>


The above is an example of the code I received from the website.
I would like to know where do I add the code you gave me? 
Also does "1.2.3.4" represent the IP's I would like to allow? 
Thanks!